# LAPACK Eigenvectors Sign Inverted for Similar Matrices

Tags: matrix, fortran, linear-algebra, lapack, eigenvector

I am using LAPACK to perform some eigendecomposition on two relatively small matrices (15x15, in this case). These matrices are from an optimisation problem, but their origin is not of great importance. They are both quite similar as it is a small step in an optimisation algorithm, so I would expect their eigenvectors and eigenvalues to be of similar magnitude, and certainly the same sign. However, after obtaining the eigenvectors of both matrices using LAPACK's DSYEVD (I have also tried DSYEV with the same result), I find that some eigenvectors show expected similarity, but others have total inversion of their signs which is rather strange. WeTransfer link for these matrices: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/784e73883eae7c63aa06aa70b64d462b20220831121100/b7519a.

I am using a module for maths that contains two functions, one for eigenvalues and one for eigenvectors.

```
MODULE math
implicit none

contains


function EVALS(matrix, n) result(eigenvals)
! Here, the eigenvalues from a square, symmetric, real matrix are calculated.
! The eigenvectors associated with said eigenvalues are not given as a result, but can be obtained with the function EVEVS.
!
! ARGUMENTS:    matrix : 2D array containing the matrix which the eigenvalues of will be calculated.
!               n      : integer which represents the number of rows/columns (it doesn't matter which as the matrix is square).
    
implicit none
integer(i4b), intent(in) :: n
integer(i4b) :: LDA, LWORK, LIWORK, INFO
real(dp), intent(in) :: matrix(n, n)
real(dp), allocatable :: WORK(:), IWORK(:)
real(dp) :: eigenvals(n), work_mat(n,n)
character :: JOBZ, UPLO

! Assigning working matrix...
work_mat(:,:) = 0.0
work_mat(:,:) = matrix(:,:)

! Initialising some values....
JOBZ = 'N'
UPLO = 'U'
LDA = n
INFO = 0

! Allocating working array...
LWORK = MAX(1, (1 + 6*n + 2*n**2))
LIWORK = MAX(1, (3 + 5*n))
allocate(WORK(LWORK))
allocate(IWORK(LIWORK))
WORK(:) = 0
IWORK(:) = 0

! Obtaining eigenvalues...
eigenvals(:) = 0.0
call DSYEVD(JOBZ, UPLO, n, work_mat, LDA, eigenvals, WORK, LWORK, IWORK, LIWORK, INFO)
deallocate(WORK)

end function EVALS


function EVECS(matrix, n) result(eigenvecs)
! Here, the eigenvectors of a square, symmetric, real matrix are calculated.
! The eigenvalues associated with said eigenvectors are not given as a result, but can be obtained with the function EVALS.
!
! ARGUMENTS:    matrix : 2D array containing the matrix which the eigenvalues of will be calculated.
!               n      : integer which represents the number of rows/columns (it doesn't matter which as the matrix is square).
    
implicit none
integer(i4b), intent(in) :: n
integer(i4b) :: LDA, LWORK, LIWORK, INFO
real(dp), intent(in) :: matrix(n, n)
real(dp), allocatable :: WORK(:), IWORK(:)
real(dp) :: eigenvecs(n, n), eigenvals(n), work_mat(n,n)
character :: JOBZ, UPLO

! Assigning working matrix...
work_mat(:,:) = 0.0
work_mat(:,:) = matrix(:,:)

! Initialising some values....
JOBZ = 'V'
UPLO = 'U'
LDA = n
INFO = 0

! Allocating working array....
LWORK = MAX(1, (1 + 6*n + 2*n**2))
LIWORK = MAX(1, (3 + 5*n))
allocate(WORK(LWORK))
allocate(IWORK(LIWORK))
WORK(:) = 0
IWORK(:) = 0

! Obtaining eigenvectors...
eigenvals(:) = 0.0
call DSYEVD(JOBZ, UPLO, n, work_mat, LDA, eigenvals, WORK, LWORK, IWORK, LIWORK, INFO)
eigenvecs(:,:) = 0.0
eigenvecs(:,:) = work_mat(:,:)
deallocate(WORK)

end function EVECS


END MODULE math
```

Now, below is an minimal example of how these functions are used within another source code file. I have printed two eigenvectors (one from each matrix) which are very similar in their values, but the signs are opposite. If you were to look at other corresponding eigenvectors, some are more or less similar (as expected), and others show this same opposite signs behaviour.

```
program eigen_test
use math

implicit none
integer(i4b) :: i, j
integer(i4b), parameter :: npr=15
real(dp) :: mat_a(npr,npr), mat_b(npr,npr)
real(dp) :: eigenvals_a(npr), eigenvals_b(npr)
real(dp) :: eigenvecs_a(npr,npr), eigenvecs_b(npr,npr)

open(10, file="mat_a")
read(10,*) ((mat_a(i,j), j=1,npr), i=1,npr)
open(11, file="mat_b")
read(11,*) ((mat_b(i,j), j=1,npr), i=1,npr)

eigenvals_a = EVALS(mat_a, npr)
eigenvecs_a = EVECS(mat_a, npr)
eigenvals_b = EVALS(mat_b, npr)
eigenvecs_b = EVECS(mat_b, npr)

print *, eigenvecs_a(:,4)
print *, eigenvecs_b(:,4)

end program eigen_test
```

Perhaps this is a problem with my eigendecomposition understanding, or maybe I am not using the LAPACK function correctly, but I hope the problem is clear and reproducible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why "certainly the same sign"?

Comment: @francescalus Well, I understand that eigenvalues are unique, but eigenvectors are not necessarily unique (just that they must be linearly independent). What is strange to me is that only some of the eigenvectors have their signs inverted, not all. Practically speaking, I am using these eigenvectors as the basis for calculating something else and if their signs are not consistent, then there are problems further down the line. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Eigenvectors have an arbitrary phase, which if you require things to be real means the sign is arbitrary, so you can multiply through by -1 and it is still an evec, as can easily be seen from the formula for the eigenvalue problem

Comment: See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27477/matlab-mathematica-lapack-returning-3-different-eigenvectors/27480#27480

Comment: Eigendecomposition algorithms are generally not stable (in the sense of "close input gives close output"), so unless you have reason to believe that the Lapack call you are using has that guarantee it'll be better to revisit the assumption that signs will be "consistent".

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for the useful replies. I will investigate this further.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks again for the help, upon some more review it does indeed seem to be related to what you say.